# hp probook white screen with error cancel image and boot to next boot order

Tags: windows-8, boot, bios, uefi

I bought HP Probook 440 G1 with windows 8 Pro. I am a ubuntu user so I wanted to install ubuntu with Windows side by side. I tried to boot it from USB or DVD ROM but was unable to do so. Then from boot options, I disabled secure boot and enabled `Legacy Boot Order` and did boot from ubuntu DVD and then I installed ubuntu successfully. I installed it on separate partition. It asked me to take disk off and reboot. On next boot nothing was working, on selecting and boot option it or choosing to enter in BIOS or any other option of continue startup I am getting one error that: it failed to boot and reboot, if error continue then contact HP Support person.  and have one preselected option/button enabled saying:

```
cancel image and boot to next boot order
```

On choosing/entering this option, system just shutdown. Shutdown mean just power off as no OS or anything else is loaded.

So I am stuck and don't know what to do. Is it BIOS corrupted ? Or some other BIOS problem or some other thing? What can be and should be done in such situation?

Comment: Its not clear if you want a working Windows installation or not.

Comment: @Ramhound First thing is that I am stuck, I can't either start my system on windows or ubuntu. Whenever I switch on my system, I only see same message and only option as told above. It is fine if I can get back to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If the computer came with Windows 8 pre-installed from the factory, then you've now got either a mixed-mode (BIOS/EFI) installation or you've accidentally wiped out Windows. Either possibility is bad. Furthermore, some HPs have EFIs that are known to be flaky and difficult to get to work with Linux, and that could be at least part of your problem. I recommend you try the following:

1. Enter your firmware setup utility and disable the Secure Boot option and the legacy boot option.
2. Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)
3. Prepare a boot medium with rEFInd.
4. Boot with that boot medium. Note that you may need to press a key (I think it's Esc with most HPs) to get a boot menu to boot the external medium. Note also that there may be two entries for your boot medium in the list. Select the one that includes the string "EFI" or "UEFI".
5. If rEFInd comes up, it should have options for both Windows and Ubuntu. Test that they both work. (You may have multiple options for one or both OSes. That's OK, so long as at least one option for each one works.)
6. Boot to Ubuntu.
7. If Windows didn't boot, post the output of `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`, typed in a Terminal window. This may reveal why Windows didn't boot. You can continue or stop for advice.
8. Install the Debian-package version of rEFInd, either directly or via the PPA referred to on the rEFInd downloads page.
9. Reboot. In theory, rEFInd should come up, in which case you've solved the problem and can stop; but if your firmware is badly broken (as I suspect it is), it might not boot, in which case you should continue....
10. In Ubuntu, open a Terminal and type `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`. Identify the partition with a type code of EF00. It's probably partition 1 or 2.
11. Type `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /boot/efi`, changing `/dev/sda1` to `/dev/sda2` or whatever partition you identified in the previous step.
12. Type `sudo mvrefind.sh /boot/efi/EFI/refind /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot`.
13. Reboot. With any luck, rEFInd will come up and give you a working boot menu.

This procedure is based on a number of assumptions, so it could go "off the rails" at various points. If so, post back for more help; don't proceed blindly if things are going badly.

Comment: It simply don't let me enter firmware setup utility

Comment: Try unplugging your hard disk. With no disk, most computers will boot into the firmware setup utility.