# HP ProBook 450 G2 - Won't boot at all

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, debian

Just got a new HP probook, came with windows 8.1. In order to install Debian 8, I disabled secure boot and enable legacy boot. Then installed debian successfully, removed the cd and restarted the computer.

Then, in the start up, a white screen appears, with this legend:

An error has occurred, please restart your PC. If the error occurs again, please contact an HP Support representative.

An a button saying: Cancel image load and boot to next boot options.

Even if a press ESC on start up and shows me a list of options (System information, boot options, etc) and select one of them, it appears the same white screen.

If anybody has some info about this, I'll be very appreciated.

(I already look at this [hp probook white screen with error cancel image and boot to next boot order](https://superuser.com/questions/791239/hp-probook-white-screen-with-error-cancel-image-and-boot-to-next-boot-order) but it was no useful)